# How to force the system to connect to a passpoint on Android 11?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-wifi, android-11

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a Passpoint configured, but the system seems to not connect to that Passpoint.

```
[...]

final WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();
builder.setIsAppInteractionRequired(true);
 
PasspointConfiguration passpointConfiguration = createPasspointConfiguration(managedNetwork.getSsid());
builder.setPasspointConfig(passpointConfiguration);

suggestionsList.add(builder.build());

wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
```

I think there is something that I'm missing, because the suggestion is added successfully, but the system is not trying to connect to it.

Comment: Did you able to figure this out yet ? I am stuck at the same point where I could save the configuration but don't make it auto connect.

Comment: I used WifiEnterpriseConfiguration instead of PasspointConfiguration and it works.  `     final WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setSsid("your_ssid")
                .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true);
        WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = createWifiEnterprise(managedNetwork.getSsid());
        builder.setWpa2EnterpriseConfig(enterpriseConfig);
        suggestionsList.add(builder.build());`